# Animate view width to X position

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to animate view width so it ends at certain `x` position on the screen depending on the int value.
`View` start x position is 192. View width should stretch and end at 478 x position depending on the value.

192 <------------- *x axis* ----------------> 478

Value has range from 1-10, where:

- 1 should indicate that the view is not animating at all and stays at the 192 point on x axis
- 10 should indicate that the view is animating fully and end up at 478 point on x axis

If **value is 8** then view should strech based on the ratio.

192 <[______________________]**(8 value)**---> 478

192 <[_______]**(2 value)**-------------------> 478

192 <[_____________**(10 value)**___________]> 478

What I do

```kotlin
fun View.animateWidth(endWidth: Int, animateCallback: (Float) -> Unit = {}) {
    ValueAnimator.ofInt(width, endWidth).apply {
        addUpdateListener {
            layoutParams = layoutParams.apply {
                val animateValue = it.animatedValue as? Int ?: 0
                animateCallback.invoke(animateValue.toFloat())
                width = animateValue
            }
        }
        duration = animDuration
        start()
    }
}
```

how to properly calculate `endWidth` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we know `width` when value is maximum (i.e. equals 10) and it is (`478 - 192 = 286`). Now we can find `width` for any `value` via proportion:

```
   10 = (478 - 192)
value = width
```

Transform parts of that proportion like this:

```
10 * width = (478 - 192) * value
```

Final formula:

```
width = (478 - 192) * value / 10
```